# How do I get mit-scheme to return a floating point number?

Tags: scheme

(/ 4 3) returns 4/3 as an answer. What is the simplest way to get 1.3...?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An easy way would be to make sure that one of the numbers in the calculation is already a floating-point number:

```
> (/ 4.0 3)
1.3333333333333333
```

Another way would be to use `exact->inexact`:

```
> (exact->inexact (/ 4 3))
1.3333333333333333
```

Comment: That's it, exact->inexact. The first isn't really an option because the number is a result of several procedures. Thanks!

Comment: I like to alias `exact->inexact` to a `~`, which makes sense both mathematically (a floating-point approximation) but is much easier to type.

Answer (score 4):

use

```
(/ 4 3.0)
```