# Output float number with decimal point

Tags: chicken-scheme

Chicken Scheme version is 5.2.0

The Scheme evaluates (/ 1 2) => 1/2.

How can I make the Scheme outputs 0.5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get mit-scheme to return a floating point number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025390/how-do-i-get-mit-scheme-to-return-a-floating-point-number)

Comment: @Jacob, that what I want.